# Associated products' pictures don't show up when I search the products

Tags: magento

I create a configurable product, a color type for example, and add associated products. Then I upload pictures to the configurable product and label them according to the color. I don't add picture into every single associated product, but upload a bulk of pictures into the main (configurable) product.

The problem is that when I search any of the associated products the picture thumbnail doesn't show up. The picture only shows up when I click the search result and get redirected to the main (configurable) product.

The issue can be solved if I add the picture to the associated product directly. But I have over 3,000 associated products on the website right now and adding the pictures manually into every one of them will require a lot of time.

Is there any way to solve the issue in a more efficient manner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The images set on the configurable product will only display for that configurable product. If the associated products are set to display on their own, outside of the configurable product, then they must also have the image data. This is because Magento treats them as an individual simple product and attempts to pull their data from the simple product.

I believe the most efficient way is to import the product image data in bulk. You can, for example, use image names that relate to the product name so that it's less confusing. But you will need to create a CSV with the appropriate data and import it into Magento.

If you only want the configurable product to show and the associated products be hidden individually, then there is a product configuration for that (per simple product).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I though that there is a way to assign pictures from configurable products to corresponding associated products somehow as they are connected via labels. I only need a thumbnail preview, as I enable search for associated products but not catalog. If not, I'll do the bulk upload. Unfortunately I'll have to rename 3k+ pictures.